# How to reduce template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

Here I have functor of the follow kind:

```
template<class T, class Foo, T Foo::*p>
struct X {
    void operator()(Foo & f) {
        (f.*p) = 12 * (f.*p);   // simple example. could be more complex `operator()`
    }

};
```

And sample struct:

```
struct FF
{
    int m;
    int r;
};
```

I want to use the functor X, but I don't want to explicitly specify template argument as follows:

```
void testforx()
{
    std::vector<FF> cont(5);
    std::for_each(cont.begin(), cont.end(), X<int, FF, &FF::r>() );  // it work, but I don't want to write `int` and `FF`
    std::for_each(cont.begin(), cont.end(), createx<&FF::r>() );     // how I would like to use it, how to declare `createx` function?
}
```

Here what I tried with no success:

```
// that is what I tried, but it could not deduce T and Foo
template<T Foo::*p, class T, class Foo>
X<T, Foo, T Foo::*p> createx()
{
    return X<T, Foo, p>();
}

// this works, but requires to write T and Foo explicitly
template<class T, class Foo, T Foo::*p>
X<T, Foo, T Foo::*p> createx()
{
    return X<T, Foo, p>();
}
```

Comment: Small fix (your “correct” code doesn’t compile): your return type declaration of `createx` should contain `p` as the third template parameter, not `T Foo::*p`. Doesn’t change the problem, however.

Answer (score 8):

I just wouldn't store the member pointer as a template argument:

```
template<class T, class Foo>
struct X {
    X(T Foo::*p): p(p) {}
    void operator()(Foo & f) {
        (f.*p) = 12 * (f.*p);   // simple example. could be more complex `operator()`
    }
private:
    T Foo::*p;
};

template <class T, class Foo>
X<T, Foo> MakeX(T Foo::*p)
{
    return p;
}
```

I don't think it is possible to deduce the types with your approach: you can't use a pointer-to-member passed to a function which is where the type deduction occurs.

**Edit:**
There may be macro-based solutions, though.

For example, you can make a class to create X instances, like this:

```
template <class T, class Foo>
struct XMaker
{
    template <T Foo::*p>
    X<T, Foo, p> make() { return X<T, Foo, p>(); }
};
```

Now, you can create a make... function to deduce T and Foo:

```
template <class T, class Foo>
XMaker<T, Foo> make_x_maker(T Foo::*)
{
    return XMaker<T, Foo>();
}
```

Which makes it possible to write a macro like:

```
#define CREATE_X(member) make_x_maker(member).make<member>()
```

Usage:

```
std::for_each(cont.begin(), cont.end(), CREATE_X(&FF::r) );
```

Comment: The question was how to write `createx`. I already have working compile-time solution and just want to reduce template arguments.

Comment: Now this is almost I need. I would accept this answer but I do not like macros.

Comment: I think this thread is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447141/c-templates-how-to-use-a-template-parameter-in-another-template-parameter-dec

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to reduce the number of template arguments you have to specify if you want an arbitraty member function pointer to be a template argument.

Instead of member function pointers you could use a normal type parameter for a functor that extracts a reference:

```
template<typename Func>
class X
{
public:
    explicit X(Func f = Func()) : f(f) {}

    template<class K>
    void operator()(K & k) const {
       f(k) = 12 * f(k);
    }
private:
    Func f;
};
```

Then, you still have the option to use a special functor that directly accesses a certain member (if you think this provides better performance), or use a more general accessor functor that does so with a member function pointer as a member.

Comment: It is allowed by Standard to have member function pointer as template argument.

Comment: Yeah, I know. The "I don't think it's possible" refers to the title of the question. I didn't say "member function pointers are not allowed as template parameters". Please read answers more carefully before you downvote. I will try to do my best next time to write answers that cannot be misunderstood. Thanks.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @sellibitze. Anyway, your code requires a `typename` when a pointer to member function is a constant. You should supply a sample how you suppose to use it.

Comment: @Alexey: I'm sorry that you think so. @Kirill: I've trouble relating your last comment to my answer. It seems we have a communication problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would have one question: do you really need to specify all those arguments ?

```
struct XR
{
  template <class Foo>
  void operator()(Foo& foo) const { foo.r = 12 * foo.r; }
};
```

This works, there is no need for an extra `make` method it just works:

```
void testforx()
{
  std::vector<FF> cont(5);
  std::for_each(cont.begin(), cont.end(), XR()); 
}
```

I prefer not to be TOO generic when I create templates.

If you need to have a more complex `operator()`, you can always do some heavy lifting INSIDE it.

Also, you may consider `Boost.Bind`, if you really wish to extract pointer functions and references to attributes.

**EDIT**:

I have an idea, that will be a bit different and does not involve any macro magic, nor even any metaprogramming magic.

*Why not simply use a typedef and be done with it ?*

Okay, may be not as automated as you wish... but you have only to type this once, after all.

```
typedef X<int,FF,&FF::m> X_FF_m; // once

std::for_each(cont.begin(), cont.end(), X_FF_m() );
```

Seems less typing than

```
std::for_each(cont.begin(), cont.end(), createX<&FF::m>());
```

repeated over and over.

I barely use naked templates in my code, I prefer to typedef them to improve readability.

Comment: It is no option. `struct XR` use `.r`-member. If I want use `.m` member do I need to define a new `struct XM`? And what about another members?

Comment: One structure per member, nothing fancy, just something that works and is simple. Of course in your example you presented a structure with 2 attributes and I would think it scales quite well to 4 or 5...